# Office365 API get content of ReferenceAttachment

Tags: java, attachment, office365api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to process attachments that were added to my event and I have difficulties in loading the attachments that has the following type:

```
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.ReferenceAttachment"
```

The problem is that for usual attachments:

```
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.FileAttachment"
```

Office365 sends **ContentBytes** in the response with the complete content of the file. In case with the ReferenceAttachment there is no **ContentBytes** field in the response. 
I didn't find anything useful about ReferenceAttachment in the doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-attachments .

However, I did succeed in finding some info in the documentation for beta version.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#referenceattachment-preview

There should be **SourceUrl**, but I don't have it in my response either.

I really appreciate your help in finding a way to get the content of such attachments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution. The reason why I wasn't able to get a source URL was the fact that this works only for **beta** version. I look forward to having it in a stable version, however, I will use beta one by that time. 
So, to make it working, we need to change version in the path parameter to beta. 
e.g.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/events/{eventId}/attachments/
```

Instead of:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{eventId}/attachments/
```

Having done that, you will be able to see the following in your response:

```
"SourceUrl": "https://.../guestaccess.aspx?docid=...",
```

One more interesting poiunt here. If it's an Office document and you want to directly download it instead of just openning it at online editor, you can change ***guestaccess*** to ***download***. Thus you will be able to download.

Comment: Thanks! It really helps me a lot. I am retrieving the ReferenceAttachment in Message, and the content is returned successfully. And the SourceUrl is still  only returned in beta, not in v2.0 as you mentioned. While in the docs, it says that it is already provided in v2.0.